# Some of the aliases you requested do not exist create Audiences

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Earlier I had Facebook personal ad account and with the help of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience I used to create custom audience. Now I have shifted to business account and trying to call same create custom audience code and it is giving me following error.

Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message '(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: createAudiences

Do I need to change marketing API to Business Mapping API or there is some error in current Code?

I am using following code

```
$audience = new CustomAudience(null, $accountId);
$audience->setData(array(
 CustomAudienceFields::NAME => $associative_arr['name'],
 CustomAudienceFields::PIXEL_ID => $associative_arr['pixelId'],
 CustomAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION => $associative_arr['description'],
 CustomAudienceFields::RETENTION_DAYS => $associative_arr['retensionDays'],
 CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE => CustomAudienceSubtypes::WEBSITE,
 CustomAudienceFields::RULE => array('url' => array('i_contains' => $associative_arr['websiteUrl'])),
  CustomAudienceFields::PREFILL => $associative_arr['prefill']
  ));
 // Create the audience
 $audience->create();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$accountId` is in the format `act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>`:

```
$audience = new CustomAudience(null, $accountId);
```

Seems like you don't have permission to create an audience in this Ad Account, try debugging your access token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken